# Get default Microphone for settings

Tags: java, windows, javafx, microphone

I am not able to detect default microphone volume settings on Windows **without using jni**. I tried several ways but it does not work as expected

```
  public static float getVolume() {
        float volume = 0;
        try {
            if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE)) {
                Port lineInx = (Port) AudioSystem.getLine(Port.Info.MICROPHONE);
                lineInx.open();
                FloatControl fx = null;
                Control[] vx = lineInx.getControls();
                fx = getVolumeControl(vx, 0);
                volume = fx.getValue();
                lineInx.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return volume;
    }
```